# How to clean hermit crab leftovers?

Tags: cleaning, hermit-crabs

I have a 5-gallon glass tank for my 2 hermit crabs. I feed them river shrimps twice a day, but they leave a lot of food untouched, which tends to settle on the bottom of the tank between and under the rocks. I have a shallow rock bed, but no soil or gravel. Is there an alternative to dumping the entire tank in order to flush out the leftovers from the bottom?

Comment: In general you should feed an amount the crabs eat in a short time. There should be nothing left over, because it has bad effects to the water's quality and then to the health of your crabs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a turtle, it produces a lot of poo, so I had this kind of tool:

[image]

The water is pulled into the pipe and pushed out trough the net of fabric, so the dirt stays in this fabric bag.

Now I have some fish, who eat the poo. Less work for me :)

Comment: What fish eats poo? Pleco?

Comment: @LocustHorde I have goldfish, they try to eat everything, floating/swimming in the water :)